# Ctrl+Alt+Key combinations not received by TextInput

Tags: qt, qml, keyboard-events, textinput, qt6

I dont receive keys with the mentioned modifiers. See the MWE below. How can I make these work? I am trying this on MacOS. Playing around with the keys shows that I receive release events only.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 100; height: 100


    Column {
        id: col
        anchors.fill: parent
        TextInput {
            focus: true
            width: col.width
            Keys.forwardTo: [list]
        }
        ListView {
            id: list
            width: col.width
            height:100
            model: ListModel {
                ListElement {name: "1"}
                ListElement {name: "2"}
                ListElement {name: "3"}
            }
            highlight: Component { Rectangle { color: 'gray' } }
            delegate: Component { Text{ text: name } }
            Keys.onPressed: (event)=>{
                if (testKeyCombination(event, Qt.ControlModifier|Qt.AltModifier, Qt.Key_J)){
                    console.warn("J pressed");
                    incrementCurrentIndex();
                }
                else if (testKeyCombination(event, Qt.ControlModifier|Qt.AltModifier, Qt.Key_K)){
                    decrementCurrentIndex();
                    console.warn("K pressed");
                }
            }
            Keys.onReleased: (event)=>{
                 if (testKeyCombination(event, Qt.ControlModifier|Qt.AltModifier, Qt.Key_J))
                    console.warn("J released");
                 else if (testKeyCombination(event, Qt.ControlModifier|Qt.AltModifier, Qt.Key_K))
                    console.warn("K released");
            }
        }
    }

    function testKey(event, key) { return event.key === key }

    function testModifiers(event, modifiers)
    { return (event.modifiers & modifiers) === modifiers }

    function testKeyCombination(event, modifiers, key)
    { return testModifiers(event, modifiers) && testKey(event, key) }
}
```

Comment: Tested it on Windows with QT6 and it works as expected. Pressed and Released events are getting processed.

Comment: ty Jürgen. reported a bug